# Write nested dictionary to an Excel sheet

Tags: python-3.x, excel

How do I dump dictionary data into an excel file? I am missing price data in output.

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOIB7.jpg)

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('myfile.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0
col = 0

crypto_price={'BTC': {'GBP': 39552.11}, 'ETH': {'GBP': 2639.38}, 'BNB': {'GBP': 321.8}, 'ADA': 
{'GBP': 1.665}, 'XRP': {'GBP': 0.7839}, 'SOL': {'GBP': 114.58}, 'DOT': {'GBP': 24.86}, 'DOGE': 
{'GBP': 0.1776}, 'UNI': {'GBP': 18.72}, 'AVAX': {'GBP': 44.54}}

order=sorted(crypto_price.keys())
for key in order:
    row += 1
    print(key)
    worksheet.write(row, col,     key)
    for item in crypto_price[key]:
        print(item,row, col+1)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, item)
        col += 1
    col = 0
    workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of problems in your code. You aren't getting the price because `for item in crypto_price[key]:` only returns the key for the nested dict. In addtion, you close the workbook too early. So to simplify, you could do:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('myfile.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0
crypto_price={'BTC': {'GBP': 39552.11}, 'ETH': {'GBP': 2639.38}, 'BNB': {'GBP': 321.8}, 'ADA': 
{'GBP': 1.665}, 'XRP': {'GBP': 0.7839}, 'SOL': {'GBP': 114.58}, 'DOT': {'GBP': 24.86}, 'DOGE': 
{'GBP': 0.1776}, 'UNI': {'GBP': 18.72}, 'AVAX': {'GBP': 44.54}}

order=sorted(crypto_price.keys())
for key in order:
    for innerkey, value in crypto_price[key].items():
        worksheet.write(row, 0, key)
        worksheet.write(row, 1, innerkey)
        worksheet.write(row, 2, value)
        row += 1

workbook.close()
```